# How can I align layer to center of canvas in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, alignment

Using **CS6**. My canvas is larger than my layer, and I would like to position the **Layer** in the middle of the **Canvas**.

I have the "*Snap To*" options in the view menu set to all three: *Guides, Layers, Document Bounds*.

Yet when I move the position of the layer, it doesn't "*Snap*" anywhere.

When I click the "*Layer*" menu, the "*Align*" submenu is greyed out.

### How do I align my layer in the middle of the Canvas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Select the *Move Tool*.
- Select the layer you want to center.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. (This creates a selection the size of the canvas which you can then align the selected layer according to.)
- Use the *Align vertical centers* and *Align horizontal centers* buttons in the top tool bar *or* use *Layer > Align Layers to Selection > Vertical Centers* and *Layer > Align Layers to Selection > Horizontal Centers*.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to deselect all.

[image]

Comment: On step 2, once I have selected the Layer, I have already selected everything. It's just a layer in front of an empty canvas. Step 3 doesn't select anything else. Since only the layer is selected, the Align buttons are greyed out. One cannot select the canvas as an object.

Comment: I just tested this. Works for me. By "select layer" I mean make sure it's highlighted in the Layers panel. By "select all" I mean press that keyboard combination to make a walking ants selection. I'll post a gif, wait up.

Comment: @MicroMachine, updated with a gif. And removed the part about this not being logical. It is actually. Once you have "selected all", meaning made a selection the size of the canvas, the layer can then be centered according to that selection.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What is "not logical" is that the smart guides wouldn't work to achieve this while they are checked...

Comment: oh..... that white pasteboard would drive me nuts `:)`  

Comment: @Scott, lol I just change it when I make gifs so it blends together with the white background on this site.  In this case it looks strange though because I include the left and top toolbar. Normally I use a middle grey, but I do sometimes change it to white when I'm working with light images where I want to visually check if the background is white or not.

Comment: LOL I've been a photoshop power user for 15 years and this was something that drove me mad more than once, never really knew how that worked. Thanks!!